# Conversion Failed when converting the varchar value 'Wired' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, casting, int, case, varchar

So I have the following logic:

```
set nocount on

select t1.*, ISNULL(t2.CountNewGLLinkIDs,0) AS CountNewGLLinkIDs

from

(select [Client_Number],[ClientName],[RemitType],[ClientServiceRep],[Backup_ClientServiceRep],       [ClientAuditor],[WirelessAuditor]
,[AccountManager],[ProvisioningRep],[BillingMonth], CASE RO.Inventory_Type WHEN 'WIRELESS' THEN 1     ELSE 0 END AS InventoryType, [NbrGLLinkIDs],[NbrInvoices],[AutoProcessCount] as [AutoProcessed]
,CONVERT(numeric(18,4), CONVERT(decimal, [AutoProcessCount])/CASE WHEN ISNULL([NbrInvoices], 1) =     0 THEN 1 ELSE ISNULL([NbrInvoices], 1) END) as AutoProcessPercentage
,[Spend],[EDI]
,CONVERT(numeric(18,4), CONVERT(decimal, [EDI])/CASE WHEN ISNULL([NbrInvoices], 1) = 0 THEN 1     ELSE ISNULL([NbrInvoices], 1) END) as EDIPercentage
,[Paper]
,CONVERT(numeric(18,4), CONVERT(decimal, [PAPER])/CASE WHEN ISNULL([NbrInvoices], 1) = 0 THEN 1     ELSE ISNULL([NbrInvoices], 1) END) as PaperPercentage
,[Import]
,CONVERT(numeric(18,4) , CONVERT(decimal, [Import])/CASE WHEN ISNULL([NbrInvoices], 1) = 0 THEN 1     ELSE ISNULL([NbrInvoices], 1) END) as ImportPercentage
,[TotalLateFees]
,[TotalLateFees]/CASE WHEN ISNULL([Spend], 1) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE ISNULL([Spend], 1) END as     LateFeesPercentOfSpend
,[NumberOfLateFees],[BalanceCarriedForward]
,[BalanceCarriedForward]/CASE WHEN ISNULL([Spend], 1) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE ISNULL([Spend], 1) END as     BCFPercentOfSpend
,[NumberOfBCFs],[ApprovedWithin5DaysOfDue],[ApprovedAfterDue],[ProcessedWithin5DaysOfDue],    [ProcessedAfterDue],[AvgDaysToProcess]
,[NewMasterAccounts]
,[BANCount] AS [NewAccountBANCount]
 FROM [RollupReports].[dbo].[report_Rollup_KPI_Approval] RO with (nolock)) t1


left outer join

--get count of gllinkid during months required
(select client_number, CASE WHEN InventoryType = 1 THEN 'WIRELESS' ELSE 'WIRED' END AS     InventoryType,
cast(datepart(mm,DateCreated) as varchar(2)) + '/01/' + cast(datepart(yyyy,DateCreated) as     varchar(4)) as BillingMonth,
count(gllinkid) as CountNewGLLinkIDs 
from glacct with (nolock)
inner join 
    (select vendor,MAX(InventoryType) as InventoryType
    FROM tbl_Ref_Vendors with(nolock)
    group by vendor) as VendorData ON glacct.vendor = VendorData.Vendor
where Client_Number in
    (select distinct client_number
     FROM [RollupReports].[dbo].[report_Rollup_KPI_Approval]  with (nolock))
group by client_number, cast(datepart(mm,DateCreated) as varchar(2)) + '/01/' +     cast(datepart(yyyy,DateCreated) as varchar(4)),
InventoryType) t2

ON t1.Client_Number = t2.client_number and t1.BillingMonth = t2.BillingMonth and t1.InventoryType     = t2.InventoryType
order by t1.ClientName, t1.InventoryType, t1.BillingMonth DESC
```

Which gives me this error here: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'WIRED' to data type int.

I've searched everywhere and tried casting it to varchar but I feel like my lack of experience its not helping. If anybody can just point out why I'm getting this error so I can learn on how to fix this that would be great!

ps: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the `case statement` of both the queries

In `T1` there is case statement 
which is

```
CASE RO.Inventory_Type WHEN 'WIRELESS' THEN 1     ELSE 0 END AS InventoryType
```

here InventoryType will be either `0`or `1` based on `RO.Inventory_Type`. So here the InventoryType column datatype will be `INT`

In T2 there is case statement

```
CASE WHEN InventoryType = 1 THEN 'WIRELESS' ELSE 'WIRED' END AS InventoryType
```

but here `InventoryType` will be either `WIRELESS` or `WIRED`. Here InventoryType datattype will be `Varchar`

Finally you are joining T1 and T2 tables like

```
ON t1.Client_Number = t2.client_number 
and t1.BillingMonth = t2.BillingMonth 
and t1.InventoryType = t2.InventoryType -- this where the problem is
```

so while joining it is trying convert the t2.InventoryType to `int` which is holding `varchar` value so you are getting that error.

Comment: Gotcha! thanks a lot for your answer, it guided me to fix it! Thanks!!